# Benefits of not passing entities to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, architecture, view, mapping, coupling

I usually see people telling that you should not pass entities to your View. They say you should use a DTO/VO/ViewModel/AnyOtherThingYouWant instead, as using an entity would increase the coupling.
Ignoring the moments where I do need some extra logic (or I don't need all the properties), I fail to see any benefits in doing this. For example, consider the following class:

```
public class Contact {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

I see lots of code that creates another class, like this:

```
public class ContactDTO {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

use it in the View and then do this:

```
someMapper.Map(contactDto).To<Contact>();
```

I can't see how better this is than simply using the Contact class, as your View would be coupled to a class that is coupled to the entity's class. So, every change in one should be replicated into the other. From my point of view, the 'middle' object is there just to add complexity, but not real value.
I know that there's no 'one size fits all' solution (as sometimes, using the middle object would make sense), but do we really need adding code like this? What are the real benefits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cited approach is a kind of purism. If you do not need to transform (reduce, merge, whatever) your domain objects and they are directly usable in your view as they are, use them - you can **introduce DTO via refactoring later, when necessary**.

So you have to take into consideration what Darin Dimitrov said but keep in mind that DTOs and similar are here to make your work easier. I recall one project I worked on - more than 90% of DTOs were ono-to-one copies of the  domain objects - this is totally useless and only adds to the maintenance cost.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way: a view is a projection of your domain. It's a specific representation of your business model. So you need to use a view model which will represent this projection. It could be a subset of the domain model but it could also be an aggregation of multiple domain models if the view requires it. The example you provided is just a specific case where there is a 1:1 mapping between the domain model and the view model because of the requirements of this specific view. But that's only one specific view. I suppose that your application has many views and different representations of your domain entities.

There are many view specific things that make your domain models unsuitable and thus the need of view models. For example validation. A given domain model property could be required in some view and not required on another view (think of Id property in Create/Update views). If you don't use a view model but have your Create controller action directly take the domain model you will have a problem if your domain model Id property is decorated with the Required attribute.

There are many other examples. If I had one advice to give you when developing an ASP.NET MVC application it would be this: always define specific view models for your views and never pass/take domain models to/from views and this stands true even in cases where you have a 1:1 mapping between your domain model and the view model.